# How to exchange two different ERC20 compliant tokens directly?

Tags: erc-20

In my Dapp, I have two different ERC20 tokens: say, `ABCToken` and `XYZToken`.  A user could give 10 `ABCToken`s to an account and in return should get 5 `XYZToken`s.

Is it possible to do this directly without converting to ethers in between? If so, what is the best way to do it (i.e. at a high level, what kind of contracts and operations required to achieve this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERC-20 defines the `transferFrom` and `approve` method. We can use them nicely in this case.

Create an escrow contract, which does the exchange for you. Your users can then allow it to take a certain amount of tokens from their balance using `approve`. When both users approved the correct amount, the escrow could then make the swap. This is done by calling `transferFrom` on both tokens, transferring the tokens to the escrow contract. Immediately after that, the escrow could forward the tokens to the receiving parties.